# How to update value into extra column in calendar app

Tags: column, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, app, update

I use calendar app to create a form for Training Course Registration. `Location, Start & End time, Description` are default column in calendar and I added new extra column (**MaxOccupy and AttendCount**). How can I update value for these extra column in edit view (in edit view only display `Location, Start & End time, Description` )

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by creating a Custom `Edit form` page via SharePoint Designer, Set it as `default form` there you can adjust the fields.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx